# When a page is comprised of php-based entries, how is it indexed?

Tags: php, html, browser, indexing, seo

For example if a page is filled with rows of database entries, how is it indexed as opposed to having individual webpages eg.

example.com/page1

```
<p>
content 1
</p>
<br>
<br>
<p>
content 2 
</p>
<br>
<br>
```

example.com/page2

```
<p>
content 3
</p>
<br>
<br>
<p>
content 4
</p>
<br>
<br>
```

vs.

```
example.com?c=1

<?php echo "content 1".'<br>'."content 2".'<br>'; ?>

example.com?c=2

<?php echo "content 3".'<br>'."content 4".'<br>'; ?>
```

Comment: The browser and the search engine will not see a difference - they only see the received html - except perhaps for the url. But you can rewrite the url as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side scripting language, so all the code is executed on the serverside and browsers or indexing engines are not aware of the code. For all a browser is concerned, the server may be running java/asp/php or anything else, it will still see them as "static" html pages.

Short answer: no difference

Comment: Thanks I was just concerned in thinking that php might have empty pages if they aren't loaded yet... but I assume the browser would crawl the page eg. trigger the display or echoing of the rows which would subsequently populate the page with data.